# Selecting from a floating dropdown in Internet Explorer using VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, html-select, vba

I'm trying to select from a floating drop down on a webpage using VBA.  Essentially, I'm writing a process to run multiple times and pull information to an excel document and will need to select this drop down each time the user runs the process so I don't want them to always click it.  I've spent the morning looking for the code to do this but have been unsuccessful thus far.

FYI, by floating drop down, I mean its the drop down where you hover the mouse over the bar and it drops down the list to select.  I'm fairly new to VBA and a 100% amateur when it comes to using VBA to query IE.  Let me know if you need other details to help me out with this issue.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without seeing the source for the page you're working with.

Comment: Hey Tim, through some more research I was able to figure out how to find the element through doc.getelemementsbytagname("Span")  do you know if I can "click" this element after this?

Comment: It's likely there are multiple span elements in the document, so you need to find out which of those is the one you want by looping through the collection returned from `getElementsByTagName`, perhaps by looking at its `innerHTML` or `innerText` properties.

Comment: Thanks Tim,  I've located the Span element I need but commanding the object to obj.Click is not performing the action.  Any thoughts?  Code below

    Dim dd As Object
    Set dd = doc.getElementsByTagName("Span")(98)
    dd.Click

Comment: Maybe the span element itself has no click handler?